# Is it possible to use multiple sets of version ranges in NuGet .nuspec files?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuget-spec

Specifying version ranges in NuGet .nuspec files is [supported](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/versioning#Specifying_Version_Ranges_in_.nuspec_Files).

However, I can't figure out if it's possible to have multiple sets of comma-separated version ranges.

e.g. [Maven Version Range Specification](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/versionRanges.html) allows this with the following syntax:

```
Range           Meaning
-------------   -------------------------------------------------------
(,1.0],[1.2,)   x <= 1.0 or x >= 1.2. Multiple sets are comma-separated
```

Is it possible to define the above when using NuGet .nuspec files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible with NuGet.